# sql to match number in string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have a table that has a comma separated list of ids in one of the fields (not my doing).  I want to know if I can use LIKE to match a number in this string?  The problem is I don't want to get similar numbers.  Is there a way to match a number with no numeric charcters on either side?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE activitiesids LIKE 6

   | activitiesids |
---+---------------+---
   |   3,16,8,6    |
---+---------------+---
   |       6       |
---+---------------+---
   |      7,560    |
---+---------------+---
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested but you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE activitiesids REGEXP '[[:<:]][0-9]+[[:>:]]';
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that:

```
WHERE ids LIKE '%,16,%' OR ids LIKE '%,16' OR ids LIKE '16,%';
```

Postgresql even has pattern matching - I don't know for mysql:

```
WHERE ids ~ '^(.*,)?16(,.*)?$';
```